# Google BigQuery: position of element in array

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, google-bigquery

Is it possible get the position of element in array in Google BigQuery?
Something like array_postion function in Postgresql?

In particular I need to get the array position of element after unnest array:

```
WITH data_table AS
(SELECT '{"fruit":[{"apples":5,"oranges":10},{"apples":2,"oranges":4}]}' AS data)

SELECT fruit, ? as position
FROM data_table, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(  data,  '$.fruit')) as fruit

fruit                     |  position
-------------------------------------
{"apples":5,"oranges":10} |  1
{"apples":2,"oranges":4}  |  2
```

I try a workaound using row_number(), but I'm not sure about sorting

```
WITH data_table AS
(SELECT '{"fruit":[{"apples":5,"oranges":10},{"apples":2,"oranges":4}]}' AS data)

SELECT fruit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS position
FROM data_table, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(  data,  '$.fruit')) as fruit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible using `with offset`:

```sql
WITH data_table AS
(SELECT '{"fruit":[{"apples":5,"oranges":10},{"apples":2,"oranges":4}]}' AS data)

SELECT fruit, i
FROM data_table, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(  data,  '$.fruit')) as fruit with offset as i
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found it in documentation

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays